# Why when I attempt to reassign a variable I receive the error, "remove this useless assignment to local variable"

Tags: java

I am trying to reassign the player variable each time one of the if statements are run, but for some reason java isn't allowing me to reassign the player and I have no idea why. In my program the play method is run multiple times, since this is a tic-tac-toe game. Beginner at java so excuse me if the answer to this is really simple.

```
public static void play(char[][] gameBoard) {
        int player = 2;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Player " + player + " enter your placement (1-9)");
        int pos = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(pos);

        if (player == 1) {
            switch (pos) {
                case 1:
                    gameBoard[0][0] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gameBoard[0][2] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gameBoard[0][4] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gameBoard[2][0] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gameBoard[2][2] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    gameBoard[2][4] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    gameBoard[4][0] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 8:
                    gameBoard[4][2] = 'X';
                    break;
                case 9:
                    gameBoard[4][4] = 'X';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            player = 2;
            printGameBoard(gameBoard);

        } else {
            switch (pos) {
                case 1:
                    gameBoard[0][0] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gameBoard[0][2] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gameBoard[0][4] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gameBoard[2][0] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gameBoard[2][2] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    gameBoard[2][4] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    gameBoard[4][0] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 8:
                    gameBoard[4][2] = 'O';
                    break;
                case 9:
                    gameBoard[4][4] = 'O';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            printGameBoard(gameBoard);
            player = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you call play it doesn't even get to the player 1 section since you always initially set player to 2. Might want to rethink this and possibly pass in player. Locally right now it's not a useful variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my program the play method is run multiple times

But since `player` is a *local* variable, the assignment has no effect, because it’s not persistent across subsequent invocations of the `play` method. Java rightly complains about this.

If you want to cycle between players there are multiple ways of doing so, but the easiest is to change your `play` method to accept the player as a *parameter*, rather than declaring it as a local function, and letting the caller of the `play` method keep track of the current players.

Next, you can drastically shorten your code by recognising that both players have *the exact same logic*. The only difference is which symbol is being stored in the board matrix. So create a variable for that symbol, and perform the board update using that variable rather than hard-coded `'X'`s and `'O'`s.